# Import host group into Docker container

Tags: unix, docker, filesystems

I am using Docker on a raspberry. I want to access the GPIO lines from the container as a user (not as root).

The raspberry run raspbian 8.0.

Looking at the content of `/sys/class` on the host:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -al /sys/class/
total 0
[...]
drwxrwx---  2 root gpio 0 Sep 27 19:05 gpio
[...]
```

The folder belongs to the group gpio.

When I launch my container this way:

```
docker run -it --privileged container-name bash
```

The user can't access the gpio folder:

```
root@f66a9f1cca91:/# su user
user@f66a9f1cca91:/$ ls /sys/class/gpio/
ls: cannot open directory /sys/class/gpio/: Permission denied
```

Even though the user is part of the gpio group, because I created the group in the Dockerfile and assigned it to my user:

```
user@f66a9f1cca91:/$ groups user
user : user gpio fuse
```

This is because, for some reason, the gpio group is lost:

```
root@f66a9f1cca91:/# ls -al /sys/class/
total 0
[...]
drwxrwx---  2 root  997 0 Sep 27 19:05 gpio
[...]
```

How to make the container recognize the group ?

As a workaround, I can change `/etc/group` so the gpio group match the proper UID. The problem is that the UID of the gpio group can change on my next install of raspbian on the raspberry.

Any way to dynamically create the gpio group or retrieve the host gpio GID within the Dockerfile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a startup.sh when the container is started. Dockerfile:

```
ADD startup.sh /root/
RUN chmod +c /root/startup.sh
CMD bash -c startup.sh ; bash
```

startup.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Change local gpio group GID to the host gpio group GID so use jedi has access to /sys/class/gpio
sed -r "s/gpio:([^:]*):[0-9]*/gpio:\1:$(grep gpio ~/host/etc/group | awk -F ':' '{ print $3 }')/g" /etc/group > /tmp/group
mv /tmp/group /etc/group
```

And mount the `/etc` folder this way:

Then I mount the host /etc folder into the container this way:

```
docker tun -it -v /etc/:/root/host/etc/
```

With this, the gpio group in the container have the same GID as the gpio group on the host and the user have access to the gpio line via the filesystem `/sys/class/gpio`.