# How to specify user and group owner of a mounted device in Docker container?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, dockerfile, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

I'm using [VSCode Devcontainer](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) and:

- I need to access `/dev/kvm` from within the container
- I don't want the user in my container to be `root`

So, I start the container with `--device=/dev/kvm` and I can access it, however I can't use it because it's owned by `root` and by **the `kvm` group from the host**.

```sh
vscode@c017a6dc1bc0:/workspaces/project$ ls -l /dev/kvm
crw-rw---- 1 root 108 10, 232 May  1 09:56 /dev/kvm
```

The `108` id corresponds to the `kvm` group on host, but it's not mapped to anything in the container. Even if I create the group `kvm` it won't work. And I don't want to hardcode `108` because this is not reliable if I ever use the Dockerfile on another computer.

A possibility is to run `chown myuser /dev/kvm` from within the container, but `myuser` is non-root and I would like the `kvm` device to be automatically usable once container is started.

I know there exist the `postCreateCommand` in VScode but it won't execute as root neither and thus won't allow my to change group of `/dev/kvm`.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ARG USERNAME=myuser
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME
    # && groupadd -r kvm \
    # && adduser $USERNAME kvm \
    # && gpasswd -a $USERNAME kvm

USER $USERNAME
```

```json
{
    "name": "Test container",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
    },
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"
    },
    "remoteUser": "myuser",
    "runArgs": [
        "--device=/dev/kvm"
    ]
}
```

What is best practice in this case? Should I somehow mount `/etc/group` in container or something else? Is there a way from the `Dockerfile` to change group owner of a device mounted by the command line?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39733110/import-host-group-into-docker-container

Comment: I was able to get something working after reading this issue and looking at the changes to the Dockerfile that fixed their issue: https://github.com/Linutronix/elbe/issues/164

Comment: Thanks @pestophagous. I'm doing pretty the same thing, I guess: `ARG KVM_GID=108` and then `RUN groupadd -g $KVM_GID kvm && adduser $USERNAME kvm`. The downside being that the group id may changes from one distro to another.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hacky solution: I installed `sudo` in the container and allowed the non-root user to execute `chgrp` without password, then added `sudo chgrp myuser /dev/kvm` to my entrypoint script.

Here an example for kvm access for jenkins:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.339-jdk11
USER root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo && \ 
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    echo "jenkins ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/chgrp" >> /etc/sudoers

USER jenkins

COPY initscript.sh /initscript.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/initscript.sh" ]
```

And the initscript file

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo chgrp jenkins /dev/kvm
/sbin/tini -- /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh
```

maybe this works for your setup, too.